# Derived Tables vs. Correlated subquery in HAVING clause SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In this example I've only got two tables with which I'm working.  I was checking to see which might run faster and the execution plans were identical.  The purpose of these queries is to find the minimum date associated with one record that's larger than the maximum date of another.  The first query is more concise (although it doesn't allow the `DATEDIFF` column the second one does).  I feel like writing a query the second way will, in the long run, be more costly performance wise, perhaps when I have many joins.  Are there any general rules about which method, or is it a case by case scenario and you let the optimizer work it out?

first

```
select c.patid,min(c.admitDate) as minDiabetesDate
    from clm_extract as c
    inner join icdClm as ic on ic.clmid=c.clmid
    where ic.icd like '250%' 
    group by c.patid
    having min(c.admitdate) > 
    (
        select MAX(c2.admitDate) as maxPreDiabetesDate
            from clm_extract as c2
            inner join icdClm as ic2 on ic2.clmid = c2.clmid
            where ic2.icd ='79029' and c2.patid=c.patid
            group by c2.patid
    )
```

second

```
select distinct x.patid,x.minDiabetesDate,y.maxPreDiabetesDate 
from
(   

select c.patid, min(c.admitdate) as minDiabetesDate
    from clm_extract as c 
    inner join icdClm as ic on ic.clmid=c.clmid
    where ic.icd like '250%'
    group by c.patid
)x
inner join 
(
select c2.patid, MAX(c2.admitdate) as maxPreDiabetesDate
    from clm_extract as c2
    inner join icdClm as ic2 on ic2.clmid=c2.clmid
    where ic2.icd ='79029'
    group by c2.patid
)y on x.patid=y.patid
group by x.minDiabetesDate,y.maxPreDiabetesDate,x.patid
having DATEDIFF(dd,y.MaxPreDiabetesDate,x.minDiabetesDate) > 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already observed that the two queries have the same execution plan.  This is not surprising.  SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  That is, the language describes what is being produced, not the method for producing it.

When you execute an `in` statement or an `exists` statement with a subquery, you *are* executing a join.  The syntax is difference, but logical processing is the same.  It is just another way of expressing the join.  There are some differences that the engine needs to take into account.  For instance, An "IN" is doing an inner join with an implicit `distinct` on the subquery.

As a matter of preference, I prefer the second version.  I like to have tables used in a query mentioned in the `from` clause when possible.

After thinking about your query, there is an easier way to write it:

```
select c.patid,
       min(case when ic.icd like '250%' then c.admitDate end) as minDiabetesDate,
       MAX(case when ic.icd = '79029' then c.admitDate end) as maxPreDiabetesDate
from clm_extract c
     inner join
     icdClm ic
     on ic.clmid=c.clmid
where ic.icd like '250%' or ic.icd = '79029' 
group by c.patid
having MAX(case when ic.icd = '79029' then c.admitDate end) <
       min(case when ic.icd like '250%' then c.admitDate end)
```

This uses the `case` statement in conjunction with aggregation functions to calculate the date that you want.  By the way, you are using a `datediff` in your `having` clause.  This is unnecessary for a simple comparison.  You can just use "=", "<", and so on to compare dates.

Comment: i like the use of the `min` and `max` like this.  hadn't thought of that before.